# submit event does not perform desired output in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling

I am designing a front-end for an email application that makes API calls to send and receive emails. First, I'm trying to successfully send an email by making a POST request to the `/emails` route passing in the **recipients**, **subject**, and **body** which I grab from the form that the user submits.
After the user submits the form, I want to load the `sent` mailbox view. My page loads the sent view but soon the `compose view` appears, and I can't seem to figure out why.

**inbox.html**

```
{% extends "mail/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>{{ request.user.email }}</h2>

    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="inbox">Inbox</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="compose">Compose</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="sent">Sent</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="archived">Archived</button>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
    <hr>

    <div id="emails-view">
    </div>

    <div id="compose-view">
        <h3>New Email</h3>
        <form id="compose-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'mail/inbox.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**inbox.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var form = document.querySelector('#compose-form');

  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){

    // e.preventDefault();

    let sent = false;

    const recipients = document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value;
    const subject = document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value;
    const body = document.querySelector('#compose-body').value;

    fetch('/emails', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          recipients: recipients,
          subject: subject,
          body: body
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        // Print result
        console.log(result);
        sent = true;
    });

    load_mailbox('sent');

    return false;

  })
  
  
  // Use buttons to toggle between views
  document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
  document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
  document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
  document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);

  // By default, load the inbox
  if (sent === false) {
    load_mailbox('inbox');
  }
  // load_mailbox('inbox');
});

function compose_email() {

  // Show compose view and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'block';

  // Clear out composition fields
  document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-body').value = '';
}

function load_mailbox(mailbox) {
  
  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';

  // Show the mailbox name
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;
}
```

Comment: why commented `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @brk when the `e.preventDefault()` isn't commented out, it shows "Email sent successfully" in the console. However, as I said I'm having trouble loading the `sent-mailbox` view after submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason that is happening is that submit event always has a redirect attached to the url in the action attribute of a form. In case the action attribute is missing, the default redirect becomes the same page.

I'd recommend you not use submit event at all. Since you are compiling form data manually anyways (for the /email request), just change the submit button to a normal `<button>` tag, and then add all the process that you are doing for submit to a simple 'click'

The code will look something like this (assuming that your send email button has the **id is 'send-email'**)

```
document.querySelector("#send-email").addEventListener('click',function(){

let sent = false;

const recipients = document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value;
const subject = document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value;
const body = document.querySelector('#compose-body').value;

fetch('/emails', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
      recipients: recipients,
      subject: subject,
      body: body
  })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
    // Print result
    console.log(result);
    sent = true;
});

load_mailbox('sent');

return false;

})
```

upvote if found helpful